# In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with usual topology, $X=\{(x,\lvert x \rvert): x\in [-1,1]\}$. Is given P homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

$P:X \rightarrow [-1,1]$ be such that $P(x,y)=x$. Is P homeomorphism.

This continuity part is difficult to imagine for me. How do I approach?
To show continuity by using definition I will have to take subspace topology of X. Still it's not very clear.
Also for homeomorphism I will have to check for bijection and $P^{-1}$.
$X=\{(x,\lvert x \rvert): x\in [-1,1]\}$

Comment: can you prove that $(x, y) \mapsto x$ is continuous? note also that $P^{-1}$ is a composition of continuous functions. In general, the graph of a function $f: X \to Y$ in $X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$ with the analogous of the functions you defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $x\mapsto (x,|x|)$. Clearly it's continuous and open. Let $\phi=\varphi\mid_{[-1,1]}$. We have that $\phi([-1,1])=X$. Finally, notice that $\phi\circ P=id$ and that $P\circ \phi=id$ so $P$ is bijective with $\phi$ as it's inverse. We conclude.